# How do I convert 12 hour clock time into 24 hour clock time in PHP?

Tags: php, datetime

I am using following function and I want time in 24hr clock format but this gives me time in 12hrs:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$timestamp =  date("d/m/Y h:i:s", time());
print $timestamp ;
?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: +1, I don't usually do pity-upvotes but you were downvoted because the code you posted wasn't formatted properly.

Comment: @Andy E's head: I don't know about the others, but I downvoted the question because there was no code at all and a simple Google search would reveal its answer. :)

Comment: @FRKT: the code was there, it was hidden from the end result by SO because it wasn't correctly formatted within a pre/code block.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the [docs for `date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php): The `H` format character gives the hour in 24h format. Also, you can use `G` if you do not want the leading `0` for hours before noon.

**Examples** (if current time was seven-something-AM)
`date('H:i:s')` -> "07:22:13"
`date('G:i:s')` -> "7:22:13"

---

For your specific case:

```
$timestamp = date("d/m/Y H:i:s", time());
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the manual the difference is in the capitalization of hour portion:
"h" returns a 12-hour format of an hour with leading zeros, 01 through 12.
"H" returns a 24-hour format of an hour with leading zeros, 01 through 23.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the manual](http://no.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), `G` or `H` give you the time in 24-hour format. You should read the manual.

`date('H', time());`

Answer (score 0):

The H format character gives the hour in 24h format. Also, you can use g if you do not want the leading 0 for hours before noon.

```
// 24-hour time to 12-hour time 
    $time_in_12_hour_format  = date("g:i a", strtotime("13:30"));
    
    // 12-hour time to 24-hour time 
    $time_in_24_hour_format  = date("H:i", strtotime("1:30 PM"));
```